# Swift accessing struct by variable

Tags: swift, struct

Let me first excuse for probably missing something basic (and the right expression)

I have a struct where I store several values for a board game. It looks like this and includes about 20 values.

```
struct Werte {

static var geld: [Int] = [] {didSet {NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ResourcenAnzeigen, object: nil, userInfo: ["which" : 0])}}
static var erz: [Int] = [] {didSet {NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .ResourcenAnzeigen, object: nil, userInfo: ["which" : 1])}}
static var temperatur = Int() {didSet {NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .TemperaturAnzeigen, object: nil)}}

}
```

There are several classes like this:

```
class KarteBlauVerbraucheErhalte {
let use: //what should I declare
let useHowMuch: Int

init(use: /*what should I declare*/ , useHowMuch: Int) {
    self.use = use
    self.useHowMuch = useHowMuch
}

override func Aktion() {
  use += useHowMuch
}
```

If I declare `use` with `Int` and use `init(use: Geld[0] , useHowMuch: 99)` the code works - but only the class variable `use` increased by 99.
`Geld[0]` doesnt change.
How can I make `Geld[0]` change?

Comment: Why is your struct only using `static` variables?

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter. And what is the protocol you are talking about?

Comment: I edited it. And deleted the protocol. It is not important I think

Comment: If you are adding an `Int` to `use`, shouldn't `use` also be an `Int`?

Comment: I am using static is the struct cause I somewhere read this would be the best way to declare global used variables

Comment: @ Rakesha I updated my question concerning your point.

Answer (score 0):

One way is this:

```
var use: Int { 
    get { 
        return Werte.geld[0]
    }
    set { 
        // You have access to the newValue by property name 'newValue'.
        // Use it. E.g.:
        Werte.geld[0] += newValue
    }
}
```

Omit it in the constructor, as it wouldn't make sense and I do not think it compiles.

Background of why your code doesn't work: you are referring to `geld[0]`, which is just an `Int`. It just passes the actual **value**, not a **reference**. But that is a whole other topic.

Comment: yeah thanks, that was the missing expression. I want to pass the reference. I tried to declare `Werte` as a class instead of a struct. So I have it as a reference. But that doesnt work either (yet)